# Set Worksheet in excel VBA return error of compilation

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button, worksheet

I have two tabs in Excel, in one I have a button that performs a certain operation, and in the other I have two OptionButtons (OB).

The first OB is named obPD.

The second OB is named obAD.

When I click the button, the following routine is called:

```
Sub PDAN()
Dim wb1 As Workbook: Set wb1 = MyWB
Dim wsE As Worksheet: Set wsE = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")

If wsE.obPD.Value = True Then
    'do something
ElseIf wsE.obAD.Value = True Then 
    'do something
Else
    'do something
End If
```

The problem is that the following error is showing:

[image]

VBA indicates that the problem is in part

```
wsE.obPD.Value
```

If, instead, I change `wsE` to `Worksheets("Sheet1")`, then the error disappears.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

Comment: @ManuelLemos Nothing changed. The error persists.

Comment: Assuming `Sheet1` is the *codename* of the worksheet in question (research codename if you don't know what that is), then use `If Sheet1.obPD.Value`.

Comment: @BigBen Ok. But I would like to shorten the term. The point is: why using SET doesn't work?

Comment: You already have an answer for that, but I still would use the codename, since that way you get intellisense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to use

`Dim wsE As Object`

instead of

`Dim wsE As Worksheet`

An "out of the box" `WorkSheet` object does not have a member `obPD` or `obAD` (that's what is triggering the compile-time error) so you cannot use `WorkSheet` as the variable type.

Better to use the sheet's codename as suggested by BigBen though.

Comment: It works! Thank you!